# iOS - Refresh data (make Api request) on Push notification in background

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using method for background refresh, works when app is active. But in background mode (app isn't killed), can't make Api request to take new data from server.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> ()) { 
        case .active:
        // works
        ...
                    completionHandler(.newData)
        case .background:

        // doesn't refresh / make api request


        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
```

Also remote notifications are enabled on background mode Capabilities.
Any solution for refreshing/ fetching data in background mode?

Comment: Did you try enabling `Background fetch` background mode as well?

Comment: yes, but doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54619493/downloadtask-gets-paused-while-executing-as-part-of-the-background-fetch-if-app), and the answer on that question can help you since it is a similar problem, maybe even a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but that isn't my case